# Getting half of records from MySQL on PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get half of values from MySQL on php.

For example; I have 6 records on SQL and i want to take 0-3 records.

I'm using the following code but it does not work.

How can i do that?

```
<?php
$test=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM urun  ORDER BY urun_id DESC ");
$output = array_slice($test, 0, 3); 
?>

<?php
while ($deneme=mysql_fetch_assoc($output)) {
    extract($deneme);
    echo '<h3> '.$deneme['urun_baslik'].' </h3>';
}
?>
```

Comment: why don't you just use a LIMIT with an offset? and what "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it gives error that `Warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\duralex\index.php on line 122` I want to take half of values on left side and the others on right side.

Comment: you're using the wrong variable for [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), you need to get it from the result set, not from the array's slice offset.

Comment: I even told/asked you to use LIMIT with an offset up here.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for answers :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: welcome but far as I can tell, I answered both questions; the fact about using LIMIT and about the error you were receiving.

Comment: I got it means about error. :) I solved it with using the result set. The other way LIMIT easier than my way. @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `limit` and `offset` for the first 3:

```
"SELECT * FROM urun  ORDER BY urun_id DESC LIMIT 3"
```

For the next 3:

```
"SELECT * FROM urun  ORDER BY urun_id DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 3"
```

Comment: @Onur Since you did say "half", and I'm not sure if you came up with this, but all you would have to do is "total" / 2 and that'd get you what you want. So your new statement would be `SELECT * FROM urun ORDER BY urun_id DESC LIMIT {$half}`. That's considering you assign that calculation to the variable $half.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper For this problem that's solve my problem. But your answer made my day actually. Thank you so much. This will be useful next time.